# How to use GIF in splash screen?

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

I want to use GIF file as a splash screen. I used [A smart splash screen for React Native apps](https://github.com/react-native-component/react-native-smart-splash-screen).

Comment: That's your goal. Important question is *what have you tried*?

Comment: i wanted use gif actually . png file working properly but gif doesn't work

Comment: Since there's zero code in your question it's hard to tell what's not working. Remember, "doesn't work" is not a very helpful diagnostic.

Comment: As png works - just use that

Answer (score 2):

GIF is not supported in react-native (Android) by default. Check [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#gif-and-webp-support-on-android) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use lottie :) 
Website    : https://airbnb.design/lottie/ 
Github     : https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android 
Lottie Gif : https://www.lottiefiles.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try use GLIDE and make **asGif()**

```
 Glide.with(ctx)
 .load(imageUrl)
 .asGif()
 .placeholder(R.drawable.loading2)
 .crossFade()
 .into(imageView);
```

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

1. Create an XML file and locate it under android/app/src/main/res/layout and name it splash.xml for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/gif_logo_image"  
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />   
    </RelativeLayout>
```

3. Include Glide package from [here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html).
4. Drop your GIF image under android/app/src/main/res/drawable and name it splash_logo.gif for example.
5. In MainActivity.java update onCreate method to load your GIF image and show it in the ImageView you included in the layout.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate( @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.splash );
        ImageView logoGIFImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gif_logo_image);
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.splash_logo).into(logoGIFImage);
    }
```

Comment: hi i followed your example, and the app crash when i open it

Comment: What about IOS?